# RDLC - Generating Duplicate rows when exporting to excel [Toggle Implementaion done]

Tags: rdlc

I have created single row group and implemented Toggle structure in my RDLC report, But when i export the report to excel my first row getting duplicated.

How to avoid this duplicate row in my rdlc excel import? Kindly do the needful.

[image]

Thanks in Advance,
Stephen.L

Comment: How are you exporting to Excel?

Comment: Also, do you have duplicates in the data source?